# Eclipse: control key hovering and control-enter very slow to respond

Tags: eclipse

I'm in Eclipse version 2019-06.  Every since I installed on this new laptop, I am facing the following problem: using the control key to hover and control-rightmouseclick to drill down is very slow, sometimes to the point of causing the screen to be disabled with the spinning-cursor icon.

I went into Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced, and unchecked everything except "Java Proposals".  I've played around with checking different things in this Content Assist section, and none of it makes much difference.

Here's an interesting diagnostic: when I am inside a jar, the problem doesn't happen.

Comment: 2019-06 is now 10 releases old, can you reproduce this on the current 2021-12?

Comment: Per default, neither `Ctrl + Hover` nor `Ctrl + Enter` is associated with content assist. Did you reconfigure your key bindings?

Comment: For all the years I've used Eclipse, it's always been the case that holding the control key and hovering for a second would open a dialog with choices "Open declaration" or "Open implementation."  Control-enter would always drill down into the focused class/method.  Unless here at my workplace they override all the default key mappings and I don't know it... all I can say is all the years I've used Eclipse, that's been the behavior.

Comment: Anyway, regardless of whether my key mappings are default or overridden... the behavior remains.  Long delays.  Unless I'm inside a jar; then it's like the good old days, with instantaneous response time.

Comment: As greg-449 already pointed out, you missed to keep your Eclipse up to date. You might face an already fixed issue or it might caused by a plugin that you have installed. So please check whether you can reproduce it with the current Eclipse 2021-12 without additional plugins.

Comment: I've updated the original with the following correction: it's control key plus a *right mouse click* that I use to drill down, not control-enter.  The control key is the bugaboo slowing things down, though, as even just hovering with the control key depressed causes a long delay.

Comment: I've exactly the same problem with recently installed 2022-03 J2EE version. Did you find a fix? I think this is related to "Code Mining" or "Hovers" in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

I finally eliminated this problem by upgrading Eclipse to 2021-03 - I had been previously on 2019-06.